# How can I configure Firefox to display the sidebar automatically for new private windows?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I use the [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) extension in Firefox, which uses a sidebar to display a list of your tabs. The sidebar is automatically shown whenever I create a new normal window but it isn’t shown on new private windows. Is there a way to get Firefox to automatically display this sidebar in new private windows?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Firefox :
[Bug 1268550 : Sidebars are not properly displayed in New Private Window](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268550).

The bug report offers a
[workaround](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268550#c7)
for private windows to manually show the sidebar.

The final decision by the Firefox team is to not allow such an option
in the meantime until some unspecified future development :

> As for extensions, we should follow along with the Firefox default and not show a sidebar unless the user explicitly chooses to activate it on the Window. For some add-ons, like a Tab Center Redux, it clearly makes sense to keep it around, but for many other add-ons it really won't. Until we are able to provide fine grained control on that for a user, we'll just have to let users do it manually with an extra click.

This workaround seems like the only solution, now and in the near future.